# add/remove class if id/class match

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, navigation

I'm trying to link up a dot navigation with a carousel type div layout and need the correct div to display when each specific dot is clicked, and also visa versa so the dot is active while it's specific div is displayed. The second part is important because I have more than one form of navigation.

Here is the project http://polyhedron.io/

The dots html

```
<div class="dotstyle dotstyle-scaleup">
        <ul>
            <li id="avn" class="current"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li id="pp"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li id="w65"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li id="trs"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li id="cc"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The (wordpress menu) project html

```
<ul id="menu-project" class="show">
  <li class="avn selected"></li>
  <li class="pp"></li>
  <li class="w65"></li>
  <li class="trs"></li>
  <li class="cc"></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dots = $('.dotstyle ul li');
    var project = $('ul#menu-project li.menu-item');
    var dotsId = dots.attr('id');
    var projectClass = project.attr('class');

    $(dots).click(function(){
        $(dots).removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });

    $(dots).each(function(){
        if (dots.hasClass('current')) {
            if (dotsId = projectClass) {
                project.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                project.removeClass('selected');
            }
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

This is the closest I could get but it's currently just adding the "selected" to every list item.

Comment: It's adding `selected` to every list item because of this: `if (dotsId = projectClass)` - should be `==`

Comment: how would `$(dots).removeClass('current');` work in your javascript when in your variable dots doesn't even **have** the class current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $dots = $('.dotstyle ul li');
  var $project = $('#menu-project');

  $dots.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var dotsId = $this.attr('id');

    $('.dotstyle ul').find('li.current').removeClass('current');
    $this.addClass('current');
    $project.find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $project.find('li.' + dotsId).addClass('selected');

  });


  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: // left
        $('.dotstyle ul').find('li.current').prev().addClass('current');
        $('.dotstyle ul').find('li.current').next().removeClass('current');
        $project.find('li.selected').prev().addClass('selected');
        $project.find('li.selected').next().removeClass('selected');
        break;
      case 39: // right
        $('.dotstyle ul').find('li.current').next().addClass('current');
        $('.dotstyle ul').find('li.current').prev().removeClass('current');
        $project.find('li.selected').next().addClass('selected');
        $project.find('li.selected').prev().removeClass('selected');
        break;

      default:
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });


});
```

```css
.dotstyle ul li a {
  color: red;
}
.dotstyle ul li.current a {
  color: blue;
}
#menu-project li {
  color: green;
}
#menu-project li.selected {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dotstyle dotstyle-scaleup">
  <ul>
    <li id="avn" class="current">
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li id="pp">
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li id="w65">
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li id="trs">
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li id="cc">
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<ul id="menu-project" class="show">
  <li class="avn selected">test</li>
  <li class="pp">test</li>
  <li class="w65">test</li>
  <li class="trs">test</li>
  <li class="cc">test</li>
</ul>
```

A bit of clarification:

You only need to bind the click on the elements you want to get info from. Also, I like to mark my DOM objects with `$` in front, and attributes without (for easier code managing). you created a DOM object

```
var dots = $('.dotstyle ul li');
```

And then made another object of that object

```
$(dots)...
```

The `$()` is shorthand for `jQuery()` i.e a jQuery object. So no need to wrap it again.

After you've bind the click event, you get info from clicked elements (id), preform class check, and then you need to look for elements in the second menu with the class that matches the id of the clicked items

```
$project.find('li.' + dotsId)
```

Since you're looking through all `$project` elements on a single click, you don't need `each()`. Just check if the list item inside has that class, and add a new one if it has.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

I've edited the code, should do what you said in the comments now.

**EDIT 2**

Edited the code again, and included the key bindings...

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. This is very close but I need it to remove the active class from the previous "test button" when another one is clicked. I'm going to add the url to my post so everyone can kinda see what I'm going for.

Comment: Ok awesome it works perfect as far as clicking the dots go. However if you visit http://polyhedron.io/ and use either the keyboard nav left/right or click the spinning dice you can see what I mean by other forms of navigation. Basically if you use either the dice click/keyboard nav/ or touch swipe to change projects I would like the dots to reflect that. 

Sorry if I wasn't super clear about that at first. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: @ChrisPerry I've added the key binding, but for the swipe you'll best be using [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/), to control the swiping action. Also you should be more clear as to what you want in your answer (since swiping and key binding wasn't mentioned ;) ) Also polyhedron probably used some kind of sliders or [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) to create their slider

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dots = $('.dotstyle ul li');
    var project = $('ul#menu-project li.menu-item');
    var dotsId = dots.attr('id');
    var projectClass = project.attr('class');

    $(dots).click(function() {
        $(dots).removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });

    $(dots).each(function() {
        if (dots.hasClass('current')) {
            if (dotsId = projectClass) {
                project.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                project.removeClass('selected');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

instead of having `if (dotsId = projectClass)` put a double equals sign (`==`) in between the two. The single equals sign sets the value of dotsId to projectClass *EVERY TIME*, which you don't want!